# Including a lightbox slideshow on a Drupal Views Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, lightbox

I'm creating a page which consists of pieces of Equipment.  Each equipment has 2-5 images uploaded.  I'm making a listing of all of these and would like to display it as follows:

```
Title 1
Overview
Slider of image thumbnails -- click to see full sized image
---
Title 2
Overview
Slider of image thumbnails -- click to see full sized image
```

etc.

I assumed Lightbox/Views/Imagecache/CCK would make this easy, but I have not been able to pull this off.  I'm also having trouble coming up with the right search terms.

Seems easy.  Thanks much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a CCK field in equipment called (`field_equip_images)`. In number of values in the settings, select 'Unlimited'
2. In the view filter by type equipment. Select the fields Title, Overview and Images(`field_equip_images`).
3. In the settings of `Images(field_equip_images)` from the format at the bottom select `Lightbox2: thumbnail->full_sized_image`

Comment: Wow.  No clue how I missed that...actually, in looking at it again, I just didn't scroll down the dropdown.  Thanks, Gokul.